# Java Swing: Initialize JinternalFrame to the top of its layer

Tags: java, swing, layer, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I have to create a multitext editor, and when you open the a new frame it should appear on top of all the others, but must remain on the same level so it could fall to the very back when needed. Whats the easiest way to do this? I have tried the moveToFront function but it doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial o [How to Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) for a working example.

The key would appear to the `setSelected(true)` method.

Comment: thanks, I was putting the statement before I added the frame to desktop.